# Hide scrollable element under a sticky element

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the second header when it goes under the first header on small resolution when it scroll, I realy don't know how to do it, I tried everything.

```
      .horizontal-scroll-table > .row::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
        background-color: red;
        width: 500px;
      }

      table thead th {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 24px;
      }
      table thead th:last-child {
        border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
      }
      table thead th:first-child {
        border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
        position: sticky !important;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 999;
      }
      @media (max-width: 991px) {
        .horizontal-scroll-table > .row {
          overflow-x: scroll;
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        .horizontal-scroll-table > .row > .col-md-12 {
          display: inline-block;
          float: none;
        }
      }
```

```
<div class="horizontal-scroll-table">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
     <table>
       <thead class="" style="background-color: #111A40;">
          <tr>
             <th>Sticky header</th>
             <th>header</th>
             <th>header</th>
             <th>header</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
     </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[here it's an example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/delicate-firefly-8tf6ui?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)  try to scroll on small size

Answer (score 0):

An interesting use case. I would have completely different approach; would this work for you?

```css
header > div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
}
header {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* actual solution */
header > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: lightpink;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>Sticky</div>
  <div>Child1</div>
  <div>Child2</div>
  <div>Child3</div>
  <div>Child4</div>
  <div>Child5</div>
  <div>Child6</div>
  <div>Child7</div>
</header>
```